# heroku run rake db:migrate, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

When I try to migrate my db over to heroku, I get this error. I think it may have something to do with Paperclip. When I rake my db locally on my computer, it works fine though.

**Error message**

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2870
   (705.4ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying NOT NULL) 
   (59.9ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations"  ("version")
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateCountries (20150113022256)
   (3.2ms)  BEGIN
== 20150113022256 CreateCountries: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:countries)
   (4.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `attachment' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb245cca098>/app/db/migrate/20150113022256_create_countries.rb:6:in `block in change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:200:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20150113022256_create_countries.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `attachment' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb245cca098>
/app/db/migrate/20150113022256_create_countries.rb:6:in `block in change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:200:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20150113022256_create_countries.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

**20150113022256_create_countries.rb**

```
class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.string :title
      t.attachment :photo

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'paperclip'

  ruby '2.2.0'

end
```

---

Comment: 20150113022256_create_countries.rb:6 what's in the file?

Comment: `(class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.string :title
      t.attachment :photo

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Please edit your question with this data. Also, show your `Gemfile` - maybe you require `paperclip` only on development environment?

Comment: `t.attachment` is a method generated by Paperclip so Heroku is not finding the gem on your system. Can I ask why you're not using `rake db:schema:load`? Running migrations like this on production to get the DB to where it needs to be can be fraught with issues.

Comment: what's the rails version, paperclip gem version? You need to provide more information to understand where this comes from. The same error you can have when using an older version of paperclip that does not have the `attachment` method on `TableDefinition`

Comment: I'm just following a guide on using heroku for rails applications, so I actually don't know why one rake command would be better than another.

paperclip version is 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `gem 'paperclip'` in `development` and `test` groups. That means, this is not included in your production environment. Move `gem 'paperclip'` declaration out of `group :development, :test do ...` block.